# EXT:C# combobox set value from Codebehind

Tags: c#, extjs, combobox

I have this Combobox:

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbEmailVer"  FieldLabel="Email verification"  Width="420" ForceSelection="true" EmptyText="Select a value..." OnDirectChange="cmbEmailVer_DirectChange" OnLoad="cmbEmailVer_Load" >
     <Items>
           <ext:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
     </Items>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

The OnLoad function in Codebehind:

```
protected void cmbEmailVer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DAL.DataContext cud = new DAL.DataContext();

            var em = (from p in cud.CTs where p.id == ctid select p).FirstOrDefault();

            if (em != null)
            {
                cmbEmailVer.SelectedItem.Value = (em.login_verify_email ? 1 : 0).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                cmbEmailVer.SelectedItem.Value = "1";
            }
        }
```

But even though I can see with breakpoints that it sets the correct value from codebehind, the combobox in the application doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectedIndex`

```
if (em != null)
{
   string s = (em.login_verify_email ? 1 : 0).ToString();
   cmbEmailVer.SelectedIndex = cmbEmailVer.Items.IndexOf(s); 
}
else
{
   cmbEmailVer.SelectedIndex = cmbEmailVer.Items.IndexOf("1") 
}
```